# How to change a Div content when selecting a value from a select with a jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hi I'm new to jQuery and I'm trying to solve this:

> When selecting a value from the dropdown (`<select>`), you need to change the content of the div tag (in red) with the selected value. Please use jQuery to solve this test, and please don't add any id/class to the above HTML code!

I already wrote a script but it does not work, can you help please

```js
var content = $( "div:gt(5)" );
$( "select" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
  content.html('6 products');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toolbar-wrapper">
              <div>
                <div>
                  <label>Product Count</label>
                  <div class="select-group">
                    <select>
                      <option value="4 products" selected="selected">4 products</option>
                      <option value="6 products">6 products</option>
                      <option value="8 products">8 products</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div>4 products</div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.value` in the event handler to get the value that was selected in the dropdown.

When you select something from the dropdown, the `change` event is triggered, not `click`.

`div:gt(5)` is not the correct selector for the div where the result should be displayed. Numbering starts from `0`, so it's DIV number `4`. You can use `.eq(4)` to select that.

```js
var content = $("div").eq(4);
$("select").on("change", function(event) {
  content.html(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toolbar-wrapper">
  <div>
    <div>
      <label>Product Count</label>
      <div class="select-group">
        <select>
          <option value="4 products" selected="selected">4 products</option>
          <option value="6 products">6 products</option>
          <option value="8 products">8 products</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>4 products</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can target with `>` & [position selectors](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).

```
$( "select" ).on( "change", function( event ) {
  $('.toolbar-wrapper > div > div:nth-child(2)').html(event.target.value);
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q9h851ka/4/)!